# ellipsis on data in razor view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-2

View:

```
<span class="details-content" id="elipses">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
</span>
```

Css:

```
#elipses{
  color:pink;
  width: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

here i'm trying to add ellipsis on  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description) but it is not working .
Q.Is there any other way to add ellipsis to data in displayfor?

Comment: You need to add `display: inline-block;` (and `5px` would not be wide enough to display them, so make it say `20px`)

Comment: :(  Still Not working.

Comment: Works fine. Refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0x8z6vqt/)

Comment: It is working.Thank you!  :)